# Css link can't call the variable from behind code in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I write it in aspx like this:

```
<link type="text/css" href='/theme<%=theme%>/top.css' rel="stylesheet" />
```

but result is this:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/theme&lt;%=theme%>/top.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

surprising is that using in js is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use expressions with `<head runat="server">` instead you have to write following code in Page_Load event to insert `<link/>`

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "Stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("href", "/theme" + theme + "/top.css");
Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `link` is inside a `<head>` tag which is runat server. The head tag is "smart", in that when it sees a `<link>` tag it lets you actually use the application relative path syntax: ~/. So if you do (inside your head tag):

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You'll see it will actually work (that is, it will expand the tilde to the proper location of your site), even though nowhere did you say runat server. The *downside* of course is when you DON'T want it to do that. :) Probably the easiest solution is to just manually build the tag yourself like this:

```
<%= "<link type=\"text/css\" href='/theme" + theme + "/top.css' rel=\"stylesheet\" />" %>
```